# Tar archive won't unpack – "Path contains '..'"

Tags: tar, osx-yosemite

The name of the file `2014-12-12 04-00-01.tar`. I executed the command:

```
tar xvf 2014-12-12\ 04-00-01.tar
```

The output is many lines of the form:

```
x ../server/: Path contains '..'
```

And then a few of the form:

```
tar: copyfile unpack (../server/logs/.DS_Store) failed: No such file or directory
```

It seems that I wasn't very careful when I wrote the backup script. How can I unpack the file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll want to add the `P` (or `-P`) flag to your command line. From the manpage:

> **-P**       Preserve pathnames.  **By default**, absolute pathnames (those that begin with a / character
>               have the leading slash removed both when creating archives and extracting from
>               them.  Also, **tar will refuse to extract archive entries whose pathnames contain ..** or
>               whose target directory would be altered by a symlink.  This option suppresses these
>               behaviors.

Try `tar Pxvf 2014-12-12\ 04-00-01.tar`. Note that you'll need write access to the parent directory of the working directory where you invoke the command.

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:
`mkdir ./dir`
`tar xvf 2014-12-12\ 04-00-01.tar -C --./dir`

Comment: `tar: could not chdir to '--./dir'`

Comment: Strange. Try `tar xvf 2014-12-12\ 04-00-01.tar -C --dir` instead.

Comment: What's the double-dash signify?

Comment: It's in the man file, I think it indicates that the letters that follow are part of the command since you can have `tar xv -C --dir -f --2014-12-12\ 04-00-01.tar`